# Cosa significa "insaccare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Una questione privata* di Beppe Fenoglio, pubblicato da Einaudi, ho letto:

> Uno che si chiamava Polo si incaricava lui dell’operazione e chiese le forbici alla madre della maestra. La vecchia stava tutta incantata, era contenta che
>   non gliela fucilavamo ma nel medesimo tempo sbalordita dalla novità dello sfregio che le avremmo fatto, e cosí non dava retta a Polo. «Sbrigati, zia, – le diceva Polo toccandole i fianchi, i capelli ricrescono, la pelle no». Intanto l’avevano presa e la **insaccarono** su una sedia, a cavalcioni. La gonna le montò su, mostrava mezze le coscie.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "insaccare" in questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo nel vocabolario Treccani, ma non riesco a capire a quale accezione
corrisponda. Si riferisce all'[accezione **3 d**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/insaccare/)?

> Ammassare persone o cose in uno spazio stretto: *insaccarono i prigionieri in pochi carri bestiame e li trasportarono in un campo di concentramento*. Come intr. pron., e più raram. come intr. (aus. *essere*), finire in una sacca, entrare pigiandosi in luogo stretto e chiuso, e spec. in luogo da cui sia difficile uscire: *nel tentativo di evitare l’ingorgo del traffico, ci eravano incautamente insaccati in una strada senza sbocco; dalla piazza de’ Mercanti, la marmaglia insaccò, per quell’altr’arco, nella via de’ fustagnai* (Manzoni).

Comment: Non sono sicuro se il significato sia questo, ma *insaccare* dalle mie parti significa anche *incastrare, infilare bene in fondo*. Magari l'hanno spinta sulla sedia al punto che la gonna le si è tirata su?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Penso di sì.

Answer (score 1):

Credo che in questo contesto assuma il significato di "ficcare".
Il Treccani  nella prima accezione di ["ficcare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ficcare/) riporta "Spingere dentro con forza".
In questo caso quindi "la spinsero (immagino prendendola e mettendola sulla sedia di forza facendo un movimento dall'alto verso il basso) con cosi tanta forza che la gonna le si alzò".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie mille! :)